# Cannot start debugger in Visual Code while developing in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I am trying to run my MEAN app through Visual Code debugger but I cannot start it. It is showing me a `Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms - (reason: Cannot connect to the target: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:58...` error. I am running Node 8.1.0 and npm 5.0.3. This is my launch configuration file

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch via NPM",
            "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
            "windows": {
                "runtimeExecutable": "npm.cmd"
            },
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "run",
                "startdev"
            ],
            "port": 5858,
            "protocol": "inspector"
        }
    ]
}
```

Whenever I execute my program I run it using `npm run startdev`, `startdev` being a script in my `package.json`. How do I start the debugger?

EDIT:

I am running the app using `npm run startdev` where the `startdev` is

`"startdev": "concurrently \"ng build --watch\" \"cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon ./bin/start.js\""`

I also tried an attach configuration as such but to no avail

```
{
     "type": "node",
     "request": "attach",
     "name": "Attach to Process",
     "processId": "${command:PickProcess}",
     "port": 5858
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the attach configuration for attaching the debugger to a node process.

You will also need to start the process with the debug flag 
So something like

```
node --debug <filename>
```

Also as pointed out by OP in the comments, debug flag has been deprecated. So use inspect flag.

```
node --inspect <filename>
```

The attach configuration looks like

         `{
            "name": "Attach",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 5858,
            "address": "localhost",
            "restart": false,
            "sourceMaps": false,
            "outFiles": [],
            "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "remoteRoot": null
        }`

More about it in the docs [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging)

Comment: Throws the same error. I have updated my question with more details

Comment: Just to clarify, you have started the node process with a debug flag right ?

It logs to console upon a successful start, something like 
```Debugger listening on [::]:5858```  
  
The `startdev` should be ```concurrently \"ng build --watch\" \"cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon --debug ./bin/start.js\```

Comment: I get it now. I am running Node 8.1.10 where `--debug` is deprecated and node is crashing. I had to use `--inspect` instead. Also `outDir` is deprecated and `outFiles` needs to be used as `"outFiles": []`. If you edit your answer to include these, I will accept it.

Comment: Ohh sure..
Let me do that